# Installation issue while installing Rodeo IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, rodeo

I am trying to install the Rodeo IDE which is downloaded from [Rodeo web link](http://bareback.s.yhat.com/download/windows)

I am facing a strange issue during installation. After providing the correct path for Anaconda installation "OK" button not enabled. How to go ahead? Any idea?. I am using latest Anaconda 3. Please guide.

Rodeo Version - 2.1.1 - 64 bit

Anaconda3 version - 4.1.1 - 64 bit

[image]

Comment: Try without the ".exe"

Comment: @Ben - Tried with no luck... :(

Comment: Hmm, try installing the latest version from [github](https://github.com/yhat/rodeo)